# Auto Increment nvarchar value in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, increment, nvarchar

I'm having a **UserID** field in my table and I need to get that value in my app and whenever I would like to add a new record it should **increment by value '1'**.

So this is how I'm trying to get the **last ID** enetered from my table.

**For Example** I'm having a value as **"A000"** and I need to increment that value by '1' so that it should become **"A001"** and so on..and after **'A999'** as pointed out by PinnyM' it should become **'A1000'**.

I don't want to write any stored procedures or anyother way from database.I would like to do it in a simpler way using my existing code.

```
 Dim strConnection As String = "Data Source=.\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=Subscription;Integrated Security=True"
 Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnection)
 con.Open()
 Dim comm As New SqlCommand
 comm.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(UserID) FROM Customers"
 comm.Connection = con
 Dim MaxUserID As Object = comm.ExecuteScalar()
 txtID.text=MaxUserID
```

Comment: What should be the behavior after it reaches 'A999'?  And is it always the character 'A' followed by a number?  And for the record, building primary keys like this is a _bad_ idea - stick with incrementing integers...

Comment: @PinnyM-First thanks for having a view at my problem and yes it should be always mentioned 'A' as first letter and next it should be increasing the value by '1' ie...as you said that after 'A999' it should become 'A1000'.

Comment: Aha, you ran into the trap! :)  You will note that 'A1000' will have a 'lower' value than 'A999' since it is character based - so `MAX(UserID)` won't work.  Even though there are ways around this, you will completely destroy any indexing trying to help you.  Is there a reason you need to use such a primary key?  The only alternative I can see it to use _lots_ of 0's so you never reach a wrap-around condition....

Comment: This is not a primary key set in my table.It's just to know the value of the cust given by the company for future reference..

Comment: So UserID is _not_ the primary key for the Customers table?  Then what is, and why don't you use that?

Comment: The one which has the primary key is only the integer value but the company askd to set an alphabet before that integer for some recognition.

Comment: So get the last primary key (`MAX()` is fine for this) and just append a letter before returning it...

Comment: You need to rethink your design. If you need an integer ID that can be incremented, make it an integer ID in the first place. If you're not sure why, create a test table, insert `A001`, `A999`, and `A1000`, and do a `SELECT ID FROM test ORDER BY ID` or `SELECT Max(ID) From test` and see what happens.

Comment: @Ken-Sure I will rethink of the design and let you know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it managed to work by doing it this way:

```
Public Function IncrementString(ByVal Sender As String) As String
    Dim Index As Integer
    For Item As Integer = Sender.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Select Case Sender.Substring(Item, 1)
            Case "000" To "999"
            Case Else
                Index = Item
                Exit For
        End Select
    Next
    If Index = Sender.Length - 1 Then
        Return Sender & "1" '  Optionally throw an exception ?
    Else
        Dim x As Integer = Index + 1
        Dim value As Integer = Integer.Parse(Sender.Substring(x)) + 1
        Return Sender.Substring(0, x) & value.ToString()
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the comments above, I would propose:

```
comm.CommandText = "SELECT 'A' + RIGHT('000', CAST((MAX(primary_key) + 1) as nvarchar(255)), 3) FROM Customers"
```

What this does is:

- Get the last key and add 1
- Cast to nvarchar
- Pad with 0's if necessary (up to 3 places)

I would absolutely *not* try to do this using a character based key as the `UserID` appears to be built.  Also, note that this is not atomic and doesn't guarantee that another connection won't insert a row before you do.  So it's really returning an optimistic value that may not be actually be correct.  If this doesn't work for you, then consider letting IDENTITY do its work for you and get the value after the row was created using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain their motivation?