# Validation issue for primary key in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am using asp.net with c# and i have a data field FID its a primary key,if i have a FID as 'm001' and next time if i put the same value as 'm001' it should give a validation issue,i need the code but as of now i have not put the validation summary.

My asp.net code is

```
  <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" 
        ShowMessageBox="True" DisplayMode="BulletList" 
        HeaderText="Validation issues" ShowSummary="False" ValidationGroup="Validation"/>

<h3> Create New User </h3>
<table> 
<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Faculty ID"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtfid" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="128px"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Username"></asp:Label></td>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter the username" ControlToValidate="txtuser1" Display="None" ValidationGroup="Validation" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtuser1" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="128px" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
```

I need a validation code so that if i repeat the same FID then it should give a error message in a pop up window

Comment: The validation regarding the uniqueness of keys in the data would need to be done on the Server. what does your code behind look like?

Answer (score 0):

Please understand the [primary key](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp) details in Google .

The primary key is a [Auto incremented field](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp%27) .

If you set the `Is Identity=Yes` for your primary key  int sql table,then it's automatically increment the value, don't need pass value from the code . and don't need any code for this  requirement .

So your table will generate the primary key is: `1,2,3,4,5,6,......`

and you can format the primary key values when you display the `primarykey` : like `M001 ,M002,M003,M004.....M011..etc`

SO it's helps to decrease the complex and length logic codes and cut the database call for good performance.

Comment: The primary key is not always AutoIncremented. In fact, it even doesn't have to be a number! Just like this question. ('m001')

Comment: okay , So he can do this format when display the primary key . So this way helps to decrease the unwanted code and good performance

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to set primary key on FID then you need to set it's **Autoincrement property** to `"TRUE"` and **IsIdentity**=`"Yes"`

And then in your codebehind do something as shown below:

```
if(ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        //Show Duplicate message here
    }
    else
    {
         //Do insertion here
    }
```

Comment: The primary key in this question is not a number. Mind 'm001'

Comment: See this I have the same question before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669252/auto-increment-nvarchar-value-in-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CustomValidator. Just drop a CustomValidator from toolbox, beside your textbox called txtfid and set its `ControlToValidate` property. Then, create a handler for its `Server_Validate` event. Inside this method, you should check if the value entered in txtfid is unique or not. I don't know how you do DB things, but if you use LINQ to SQL, you will have something like:

```
protected void CustomValidator2_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    TestDBDataContext db = new TestDBDataContext();
    args.IsValid = (db.Faculty.Count(x => x.FID == args.Value) == 0);
}
```

This is a very simple example. If don't want the user to see the error message associated to CustomValidator beside the textbox (message only visible in Summary) set its `Display` property to `None`.

Comment: Hey , He does not use Linq , The OP have simple asp.net webform ,and The OP have no't any contex class . Your code is simple but it's helps to write more complex code .

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion without seeing code behind?

Comment: ha ha . That's simple , The OP have asp.net webform controls(asp.net textbox) and he also mention it in tag option .

Comment: Asp.Net webform controls mean no LINQ?? Are you serious?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch primary key exception by using SQLException class. When the code catches this type of exception check the exception number.

If the exception number is 2627 then you can stop user from inserting the record. Please check this link

http://www.gyansangrah.com/ArticleContent.aspx?ID=catch_primary_key_violation_exception_in_ado_net

Please let me know if you need some other information